# Count all Comma In Selection or selected text

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2007, word-2003

I want to count all Commas "," that occur only in selected text after that I will use Count as `Integer` to run the `loop`

My question is how do i Count `,` as following Image shows:

[image]

I Don't know how to use `split` and `ubound`. what is wrong with following code?

```
Sub CountComma()
Dim x As String, count As Integer, myRange As Range

Set myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Range.Start, Selection.Range.End)

 x = Split(myRange, ",")
  count = UBound(x)

  Debug.Print count

End Sub
```

Comment: You've been asking quite a few questions the past few days - and been getting answers. But you haven't provided any feedback on those answers in the form of comments, upvotes or marking as "the" answer. You should perhaps take a moment to read the site guidelines in the [help]… This particular question lacks any research or sign of effort on your part.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for pointing out. I am new to this site, I will read guideline. on the other hand I marked all answers which helped me in solving my issues and leave those which need some more attention. you can visit my profile  and check **upvotes** to those answers which are marked as **"the answer"**. and sorry language :) English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: The code example is a possible approach and should search only the selection/range. If it's not, then it's probably an issue with some of the Find settings. However, the Answer KyloRen has posted is the most efficient method of getting the information and the one I would have suggested.

Comment: @CindyMeister see! I some time do not add my sign of effort because I want to see what others are doing in most efficient way. and thanks for helping me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple split will work.

```
x = Split("XXX,XXX,XXX,XXX,XX,XX", ",")
  Count = UBound(x)
  Debug.Print Count
```

B/c the array starts at zero you can take to `Ubound` number as is.

EDIT:
To use a `range` .

```
x = Split(Range("A1").Value, ",")
```

To break down the code.

```
Split("A string value","Delimiter to split the string by")
```

And if you want a single line of code than,

```
x = UBound(Split(myRange, ","))
```

Comment: I manage to add `Range` and your given code (edited the Original question) and it turn out I don't know much about `Split` and `Ubound` . can you add some more info?

Comment: Thanks for Helping.
I got your point, posted final answer on my behalf.

Comment: for sake of changing answer. I am not here to get all credit. I just selected the working code as final answer.

Comment: No worries, I gave you a vote as I think you have tried and succeeded in understanding the answers. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

your code is wrong in the initial declaration statement of `x` variable as of `string` type , since in the subsequent statement

```
with x = Split(myRange, ",")
```

you'd want `x` hold the return value of `Split()` function which is an array (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278528(v=office.15).aspx)), thus of `Variant` type

so you have to use

```
Dim x As Variant
```

But you can simplify your code as follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub CountComma()
  Dim count As Integer

  count = UBound(Split(Selection, ","))
  Debug.Print count   

End Sub
```

since:

- you don't need any `Range` type variable to store `Selection` object into, being `Selection` the selected range already (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198352(v=office.15).aspx))
- you don't need the `x` `Variant` variable neither, feeding `UBound()`function (which expects an array as its first argument) directly with the `Split()` function which, as we saw above, returns just an array!

Finally I'd give out an alternative method of counting commas in a range

```
Sub CountComma()
  Dim countAs Integer
  count = Len(Selection) - Len(Replace(Selection, ",", ""))

  Debug.Print count
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks your answer is very thoughtful. Most simplest way of doing same job.

Comment: You're welcome. And if you found my answer useful, you may want to up-vote it ... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to KyloRen and Cindy Meister, Now I can use `split` and `Ubound` for Counting `,` in `selection.text`.

Following is working Code:

```
    Sub Count_Words()
        Dim WrdArray() As String, myRange As String

        myRange = ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Range.Start, Selection.Range.End)

        WrdArray() = Split(myRange, ", ")

        MsgBox ("Total , in the string : " & UBound(WrdArray()))

    End Sub
```